# List index out of range when specifying column in numpy

Tags: python, numpy, csv, indexoutofrangeexception

I have been tasked with extracting data from a specific column of a csv file using numpy and loadtxt. This data is on column D of the attatched [image.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5f9Rf.png) By my logic i should use the numpy paramter `usecols=3` to only obtain the 4th column which is the one I want. But my [output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qQkps.png) keeps telling me that the index is out of range when there is clearly a column there. I have done some prior searching and the general consensus seems to be that one of the rows doesn't have any data in the column. But i have checked and all the rows have data in the column. [Here is the code Im using highlighted in green.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2hYu1.png)Can anyone possibly tell me why this is happening?

```
data = open("suttonboningtondata_moodle.csv","r")

min_temp = loadtxt(data,usecols=(3),skiprows=5,dtype=str,delimiter=" ")
print(min_temp)
```

Comment: There is a way to ask a homework question. There is a way to ask questions. This is neither. Rewrite your question and google for an answer first.

Comment: Check your delimiter.

Comment: It was the delimiter! Thank you so much

Comment: Unfortunately for this assignment I have to use numpy, otherwise I would give pandas a shot, thank you anyway

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added a comma instead of whitespace for the delimiter value and it worked. I have no idea why though

Answer (score 0):

I will suggest you use another library to extract your data. The pandas library works well in this regard.
Here is a documentation link to guide you.
[pandas docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.html)